# The Merchandise Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> People normally wear my merchandise.
>   I join things, I separate things, I am in the things.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 2):

> a zip (or possibly velcro)

because

> a zip joins things together when zipped up, and separates things when unzipped.
>   a zip is worn as part of clothing.

Comment: read first line. you were close.

Comment: I suspect the answer is YKK, the [manufacturer of 90% of the world's zippers](https://www.intelligentinvestor.com.au/2012/07/ykk-the-zipping-monopoly).  I'm leaving a comment on this answer instead of leaving my own, as this answer was basically *90% of the way there*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are...

> Thread?

"People normally wear my merchandise."

> People purchase and wear clothing, which are made of threads.

"I join things,"

> Thread can be used to tie things together, thereby joining them.

"I separate things,"

> Thread can be used with fabric to sew a pocket. Things inside a pocket are separated from things outside the pocket.

"I am in the things."

> Threads are in clothing.

Comment: for "I separate things" perhaps a "Thread" in the programming sense, where different tasks are said to "Run on different threads" and it is common to 'start a new thread' when you want something to run separately.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> **Cleavage Couture**, makers of the Cleavage Couture Bra.

People normally wear my merchandise.

> Well, yes.

I join things, I separate things, I am in the things.

> ```
>    cleavage
>     n 1: the state of being split or cleft;
>            "there was a cleavage between the liberal and conservative members"
>          [...]
>       4: the line formed by a groove between two parts
>          (especially the separation between a woman's breasts)
>       5: the act of cleaving or splitting
>
>   cleave
>     v 1: separate or cut with a tool, such as a sharp instrument
>       2: make by cutting into
>       3: come or be in close contact with; stick or hold together and
>          resist separation
> ```
>
> so that "cleavage"[5] via "cleave"[3] means cleavage joins things;
>  "cleavage"[1] separates things, and
>  "cleavage"[4] is what you're involved in.

<sub>(I suspect your riddle is too underspecified and may be **Too Broad**.)</sub>